# C server socket's read function writing dirty buffer

Tags: c, linux, sockets, read-write

I have the following C server and client:

**SERVER**

```
int main(int argc, char **argv) {
    int listenfd, connfd, n;
    struct sockaddr_in servaddr;
    char recvline[1025];  

    if ((listenfd = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, 0)) < 0) {
        perror("Socket Error");
        exit(1);
    }
    servaddr.sin_family = AF_INET;
    servaddr.sin_addr.s_addr = htonl(INADDR_ANY);
    servaddr.sin_port = htons(1024);

    if (bind(listenfd, (struct sockaddr *) &servaddr, sizeof(servaddr)) < 0) {
        perror("Bind Error");
        exit(1);
    }
    if (listen(listenfd, 1024) < 0) {
        perror("Listen Error");
        exit(1);
    }

    while(1) {
        printf("Waiting connection...\n");

        if ((connfd = accept(listenfd, (struct sockaddr *) NULL, NULL)) < 0) {
            perror("Accept Error");
            exit(1);
        }

        printf("Waiting for input.\n");   

        while ((n = read(listenfd, recvline, sizeof(recvline))) > 0) {
            recvline[n] = '\0';
            if (fputs(recvline, stdout) == EOF) {
                fprintf(stderr,"fputs Error\n");
                exit(1);
            }
        }

        printf("Read string: %s", recvline);
        close(connfd);
    }
   }
```

**CLIENT**

```
int main(int argc, char **argv) {
    int sockfd, connfd, n;
    struct sockaddr_in servaddr;
    char buff[1025], matricola[15];

    if ((sockfd = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, 0)) < 0) {
        perror("Socket Error");
        exit(1);
    }

    servaddr.sin_family = AF_INET;
    servaddr.sin_port = htons(1024);

    if (inet_pton(AF_INET, argv[1], &servaddr.sin_addr) < 0) {
        fprintf(stderr,"inet_pton Error for %s\n", argv[1]);
        exit (1);
    }

    if (connect(sockfd, (struct sockaddr *) &servaddr, sizeof(servaddr)) < 0) {
        fprintf(stderr,"Connect Error\n");
        exit(1);
    }

    printf("Matricola: ");
    fflush(stdin);    
    scanf("%s", matricola);    
    strcpy(buff, matricola);    
    if (write(sockfd, buff, strlen(buff)) != strlen(buff)) {    
        perror("Write Error");   
        exit(1);    
    }    
    close(connfd);
    }
```

I'm under Linux, I can start the server correctly from terminal that starts listening, but when I open another terminal instance and start the client, the server automatically executes the rest of the code and prints **Read string: ###** (random characters like dirty buffer). Is this because the server is not waiting for the client to write? What am I doing wrong in this code?

What I tought was that the server didn't wait for the client to write something, so I tried to add a sleep(10) before the server's read command, but nothing changes.

EDIT: I edited the read function from

```
n = read(listenfd, recvline, strlen(recvline) + 1)) > 0
```

to

```
n = read(listenfd, recvline, sizeof(recvline))) > 0
```

But still it doesn't fix the issue.

Comment: `strlen(recvline)` most propably does not do what you expect. You might like to RTFM for `strlen()`. http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/strlen.3.html

Comment: I used sizeof(recvline) the beginning but then I changed it to what you saw for testing purposes, now I reverted back the code and edited the question, but I still got the same problem.

Comment: Hey, not fair mutating the question to invalidate answers without at least commenting on the change, and stating that making the change doesn't solve the problem!

Comment: Sorry. Doing this right now. ^^

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change your inner while cycle to read from the connected file descriptor, not the listening file descriptor, like this:

```
 while ((n = read(connfd, recvline, strlen(recvline) + 1)) > 0) {
        recvline[n] = '\0';
        if (fputs(recvline, stdout) == EOF) {
            fprintf(stderr,"fputs Error\n");
            exit(1);
        }
    }
```

Comment: I passed the wrong variable **listenfd** instead of **connfd** and that was the mistake. Thank you very much, I'll be more careful next times and will make sure to understand the read() function better.

Answer (score 2):

This line

```
 while ((n = read(listenfd, recvline, sizeof(recvline))) > 0) {
```

tries to read from the listening socket. This does not make sense.

You need to read from the accepted socket. So it should be:

```
 while ((n = read(connfd, recvline, sizeof(recvline))) > 0) {
```

---

Moreover it should be

```
 while ((n = read(connfd, recvline, sizeof(recvline) - 1)) > 0) {
```

as after the `read()` you do

```
    recvline[n] = '\0';
```

For the OP's source if you'd have read `sizeof recvline` bytes `recvline[n]` would address one **behind** the last element of `recvline`.

Comment: Indeed, I did like you said adding that **-1** and it works flawlessly, thank you very much